# SQL Query to return one record for a column with duplicated values based on the date of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am sure this question may have been answered before, but it's hard to phrase, and I've spent a couple of hours on Google and still not found a solution.

I have a table (view) that has a record of device serial numbers that are rented out. The row is created by a sales order when we ship out a device (Status = Shipped) and then when the device is returned the same record is updated (Status = Returned). The TransDate is updated when shipped and then when returned.

Now a device is back in our warehouse, we will rent it out again, this time with a new order (because it will 99% be a different customer). So we get a new row in the table, with a new order number but, of course, with the same serial number.

Here is some example data (but there are many additional fields in the real table)

```
SerNo   TransDate   OrdNo   Status     (record id for describing the issue)
1111    20170105    1234    Returned   1
2222    20161220    1235    Shipped    2
3333    20170105    1235    Returned   3
4444    20170105    1236    Returned   4
1111    20170115    1311    Returned   5
4444    20170110    1312    Shipped    6
6666    20170110    1313    Shipped    7
1111    20170125    1401    Shipped    8
```

My challenge is that I need a Select query that will return just *one* record for every *serial number* that is in the table... and where there is more than one record for the same serial number, I need the one with the latest date.

In other words the result would include record id's:
2, 6, 7, 8 (devices out at customers) AND 3 (because this has been returned but not re-shipped).

(Records 1, 4, 5 have been returned, but then rented out again, so they are now just historical records and do not represent current status).

I know GROUP BY will not work because I have to aggregate the other fields, and I need all the other fields (there are many more) from the record with the latest date for a given serial number.

We are running this on SQL Server 2012.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a unique `RecordId` (or some other column) for each row? Something you could use with `Row_Number()` partitioned by `SerNo` and ordered by `TransDate` (descending) to identify the latest row for each (row number = 1)? fyi: SQL Server 11 is SQL Server 2012 to most users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number` function to get the first row for each serno ordered by descending transdate.

```
select serno,transdate,ordno,status
from (
select t.*, row_number() over(partition by serno order by transdate desc) as rnum
from data t
) x 
where rnum=1
```